# SonarQube Not Comparing with BASELINE version

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube version 6.7 with SonarJava 5.6 and configured leakPeriod as version i.e. BASELINE.

1. As you can see in the following image the BASELINE version has 3bugs and 5 code smells:
   [image]
2. During analysis at 8:50 and 8:54PM the code smells reduced to 3:
   [image]
3. And at the last analysis the bugs and code smells are same as BASELINE version (i.e. 3bugs and 5 code smells):
   [image]

**Question:**
My understanding is that each sonar run is compared against with the BASELINE version. So since the last analysis is same as the BASELINE, the quality gate should **not** fail.
But here it is failing and seems to compare with the previous_version. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help